# knockout js showing related objects(selected id) on click

Tags: arrays, knockout.js

I'm new to Knockout js and need some advice. What I am trying to do (the correct way) is have orders listed in a grid and a "production" button that when it is click, will show only the production objects that have matching id's to the order id. I'm trying to wrap my head around Knockouts binding, but I think I am over thinking things.

right now I have 2 objects  Order and Production with are observable arrays filled with observables. Order has value of orderId and Production have value of prodId that I am checking for a match. I'm now wondering if I should not make this on object with mutli-dimensional array. Would it be easier to show selected data that way?

here is an example of the initial arrays

```
       var initProduction = [
        new Production({
            proId:"183175",
            pType:"Art TIme",
            startTime:"11:20",
            stopTime:"11:50",
            totalTime:"",
            by :"MJ"
        })
        var initData = [
           new Order({
           date:"06-09-2014",
           orderId:"183175",
           name:"Columbus Africentric",
           dateRec:"05-23-2014",
           rushDate:"",
           totalQty:55,
           parts:"1",
           auto:"No",
           type:"Local",
       })
       ]
```

so should I combine into a multidimensional array? And if so, how would I do that? And how would I create a click event to show related data in another table showing only the production info.

I hope this makes sense and someone can help me. I apologize for my ignorance.

here is a stripped down version of my html bindings

```
<table>
<tbody data-bind="foreach:filteredOrders">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label class="read" data-bind="text:orderId, visible:true" />
      </td>
      <!-- controls -->
       <td class="tools">
    <button class="button toolButton" data-bind="click: $root.showSummary">Show Production</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<h3>Production Summary</h3>
<table class="ko-grid" id="menu" > 
<tbody data-bind="foreach:filteredProds">
 <tr>
   <td>
    <div>
      <label class="read" data-bind="text:proId, visible:true" /> 
     </div>
     </td>
  </tr>     
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: have you looked at the knockoutjs mapping plugin?

Comment: if I use mapping should I create one multi-dimensional object? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Your situation is essentially a foreign key relationship like in a database. Give me a couple hours and I will try to whip something up. You essentially want all orders that are in production or vice versa?

Comment: vice versa, and exactly!

Comment: This is essentially what you need to do: http://jsfiddle.net/H4QfX/

Comment: Normally the order would have a foreign key that would join to production. Do you have this in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just have an orders array and then link the production object to the order.

```
var model = {
    orders: [
        {
            date:"06-09-2014",
            orderId:"183175",
            name:"Columbus Africentric",
            dateRec:"05-23-2014",
            rushDate:"",
            totalQty:55,
            parts:"1",
            auto:"No",
            type:"Local",
            production: {
                proId:"183175",
                pType:"Art TIme",
                startTime:"11:20",
                stopTime:"11:50",
                totalTime:"",
                by :"MJ"
            }
        },
        {
            date:"06-09-2014",
            orderId:"183176",
            name:"Angle Africentric",
            dateRec:"05-23-2014",
            rushDate:"",
            totalQty:55,
            parts:"1",
            auto:"No",
            type:"Local"
        }
    ]
};
```

In the above json the second order doesn't have a production object.

Then in the viewModel I would use a computed which will return the orders depending on if all orders or only production orders should be shown. I've created a toggle here which is linked to the button.

```
var ViewModel = function (model) {
    var self = this;

    self.orders = $.map(model.orders, function (order) { return new Order (order); });

    self.toggleProductionMode = function (order) {
        order.showProductionOrder(!order.showProductionOrder());
    };
};

var Order = function (order) {
    var self = this;

    ko.utils.extend(self, order);

    self.showProductionOrder = ko.observable(false);
};
```

View:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: orders">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: orderId"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="if: production"><button data-bind="click: $root.toggleProductionMode">Toggle Production Orders</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-bind="visible: showProductionOrder, with: production">
            <td colspan="3">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>proId</th>
                        <th>pType</th>    
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-bind="text:proId"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text:pType"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/X3LR6/2/

Comment: This is almost exactly what I am looking for, but I still need to be able to only show production for a Chosen Order. I am having a hard time figure out how to refresh the HTML bindings to only show production cue of only the Order that I have clicked on(selected either with a click of a button or some other means). Does that make sense?

Comment: Just so I am understanding this right, I have to keep the "with" binding inside of the "foreach" binding. Is that correct? I can not do this showing 2 separate tables. One for Orders and one for Productions? I guess I can figure out how to hide the other Orders when I select the toggleProductions button. I can do that, right?